# Trouble selecting object ID with wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I'm using multiple instances of jwplayer on my page that generate random keys onto the end of the player ID every time the page loads. Example: `jwplayer_ad1_012` and on next refresh `jwplayer_ad1_123`. 
I'm trying to select the player and make it play(I am aware of autoplay) by using the javascript `$("object[id^='jwplayer_ad1_']").jwplayer().play();` and that's throwing up an error. I tried to assign `$("object[id^='jwplayer_ad1_']")` to a var and use `testvar.jwplayer().play();` and that didn't work either as console says
*Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jwplayer is not a function* so i did `window.alert(testvar);` to make sure the var was being set and the alert just said *[object Object]*

Can I have some insight to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is object in object[id^='jwplayer_ad1_']? Do you have 'object' elements?

Comment: *"...and that's throwing up an error..."* ***What*** error?

Comment: It's the flash player that my jwplayer code generates. I thought `object[id^='jwplayer_ad1_']` would just select any dom object that has "jwplayer_ad1_" in the ID

Comment: @n1nja: It'll select any `object` element whose `id` attribute *starts with* `jwplayer_ad1_`, yes.

Comment: Can you replicate it in a fiddle?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder _Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jwplayer is not a function_ sto i did `window.alert(testvar);` to make sure the var was being set and the alert just said _[object Object]_

Comment: Do you have a link you can share?

Comment: sure, [link](http://itube247.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe `jwplayer` is a jQuery plugin, but you're trying to call it like one.

[This page](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413074-javascript-api-quick-start) suggests that in order to use `jwplayer`, you call the `jwplayer` function and pass it the `id` of the element to use, or an index (0 = the first one).

So if you want to play the first one, simply:

```
jwplayer(0).play();
```

or (apparently `0` is the default):

```
jwplayer().play();
```

If you want one of the others, you can use a higher index.

**If** you wanted to do it by `id` instead, you could find the `id`:

```
var id = $("object[id^='jwplayer_ad1_']").attr("id");
```

...and then do this:

```
if (id) { // Did we find one (the above returns `undefined` if there weren't any)
    jwplayer(id).play();
}
```

...but that's a very roundabout way.

Comment: This was perfect. It seems I was missing the `.attr("id");` So to make sure I understand this, the `$("object[id^='jwplayer_ad1_']")` just selects the object as a whole and the `.attr("id");` is selecting the individual attribute of the object?